# Azure .Net Framework 4.8 backward compatibility

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-web-app-service, .net-framework-version

I have ASP.Net MVC application built on target framework - 4.5 and In Azure .Net Framework version was set to 4.7. application is working fine. I have Visual Studio 2017 version installed supporting .Net Framework till 4.7.2

[image]

recently, we received mail from Azure mentioning about platform upgrade to 4.8. I wanted to know is it mandatory to target application to 4.8 version?. Is 4.8 version compatible with 4.5?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your .NET 4.5 application should continue to run fine on .NET 4.8. However, it's always wise to test it just in case.

Comment: Thanks @markxa. for test purpose on local, which .net framework pack should I download - runtime or developer. here is link - https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net48

Comment: The App Service will have the runtime version installed, you shouldn't need the developer bits (unless you want to recompile against 4.8, which is a different exercise).